# ASP.NET tracing in app_code directory?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, trace

Has anyone been able to successfully execute a Trace.Warn statement from a function in a class in the app_code directory? I haven't had any luck and I'm wondering if it's possible.

(Well, I'm sure it's possible, I just need to figure out how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Have you tried:

```
HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn("message");
```

Remember that you have to enable tracing in the web.config

```
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" mostRecent="true"/>
```